# How can I print contents of array in ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara

Can anyone help. I have created a method in ruby capybara to find all link elements on a web page matching certain criteria and stored them in an array. I want to iterate through the items in the array and print them to the console. My code for doing this is :

```
case_list = []   
case_list.push(results_page.list_cases.to_s)   
case_list.each do |item|
     puts item   
end
```

but all I get printed is `#<Capybara::Result:0x007fd0a4ef4350>`

Comment: Can you show your method that finds all the links, there may be a cleaner way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`case_list` is an array with one element, `list_cases` converted as a string!

If `list_cases` is already an array, you could iterate directly on it.
Note that a [`Capybara::Result`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Result) is itself a collection of [`Element`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element), so you need to iterate again :

```
results_page.list_cases.each do |capybara_result|
  capybara_result.each do |element|
    puts element.text
  end
end
```